# Compiling linked ( not copied ) files using NDK

Tags: android, opengl-es, android-ndk

I'm building an OpenGL based app - writing in native C/C++.

I want to have my native files in a single location and only linked to the project ( so when I edit them in XCode/Eclipse the other project already has the updated files ). However, I can't figure out how to get ndk-build to build files that aren't actually in the JNI folder. Symbolic links ( in OSX ) didn't do the trick.

I keep getting

```
make: *** No rule to make target `/Developer/SDKs/android-ndk-r7b/build/core/myfile.cpp', needed by `obj/local/armeabi/objs/glHelloArrow/myfile.o'.  Stop.
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have a similar issue with cross-platform codebase. I've not found any way to do this.

My workaround is to create a symlink from my source code root directory into `jni`, so I can give the NDK build system paths like `jni/link/common/foo.c`.

Just be sure that you remove the symlink if you ever need to run tools that do recursive directory traversals...

Answer (score 1):

I build outside of JNI folder on Windows. My Android.mk includes a makefile in a different folder:

```
LOCAL_PATH := $(MY_WORKSPACE)/path/jni
include  $(MY_WORKSPACE)/path/jni/Src.mk
```

where the actual sources are listed:

```
LOCAL_SRC_FILES := \
    a.cpp \
    b.cpp \
    etc.
```

One caveat is - `make` does not work right with relative paths. Or rather, it does, but assumes the path to be relative to the current folder, which in case of the `ndk-build` process can be all over the place. Thus the env variable that denotes the root of the file location.

Some details [here](/questions/8074372/make-include-in-makefiles-be-relative-to-the-files-location).